# Bokeh: JS callback when double-click on circle

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh

I am showing some information on a webpage when single-clicking circles, now I would like to add some interaction on double-clicking: open a new tab loading a url hopefully using [`OpenURL`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/callbacks.html#bokeh.models.callbacks.OpenURL).

This is my current code:

```
p = bokeh.plotting.figure(tools=TOOLS)
cr = p.circle(y_true[:, 1], y_pred[:, 1], size=5, source=source)

taptool = p.select(type=bokeh.models.TapTool)
taptool.callback = bokeh.models.CustomJS(args={'circle': cr.data_source},
        code=self.show_data_callback())
```

`show_data_callback` just returns a string with JS code that shows information about the clicked circle.

Comment: The current `TapTool` only supports a single tap. It might not be difficult making it configurable to double click as well. If you are interested in pursuing a PR to add this functionality, we are always happy to answer questions and help people get started in Bokeh dev. Alternatively [Bokeh is extensible], you could certainly write a custom tool extension to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the tutorial in [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) and with some help from the bokeh chat I created an extension with different actions for the click and double click actions:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import Instance
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, TapTool, CustomJS, OpenURL
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file('tool.html')

JS_CODE = """
p = require "core/properties"
TapTool = require "models/tools/gestures/tap_tool"

class NewTapToolView extends TapTool.View

  _get_canvas_position: (e) ->
    canvas = @plot_view.canvas
    vx = canvas.sx_to_vx(e.bokeh.sx)
    vy = canvas.sy_to_vy(e.bokeh.sy)
    return [vx, vy]

  _tap: (e) ->
    console.log('click')
    [vx, vy] = @_get_canvas_position(e)
    append = e.srcEvent.shiftKey ? false
    @_select(vx, vy, true, append)

  _doubletap: (e) ->
    console.log('double click')
    [vx, vy] = @_get_canvas_position(e)
    append = false
    @_select(vx, vy, true, append)

class NewTapTool extends TapTool.Model
  default_view: NewTapToolView
  type: "NewTapTool"

  tool_name: "New Tap Tool"

  @define { source: [ p.Instance ] }

module.exports =
  Model: NewTapTool
  View: NewTapToolView
"""


class NewTapTool(TapTool):
    __implementation__ = JS_CODE
    source = Instance(ColumnDataSource)


x = y = [i for i in range(10)]
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=[NewTapTool(source=source)])
plot.title.text = "Double click on a dot to test"
plot.circle('x', 'y', source=source, size=10)

newtaptool = plot.select(type=TapTool)
newtaptool.callback = OpenURL(url="https://en.wikipedia.org/")

show(plot)
```

The example simply opens Wikipedia when double clicking a circle. In the `_tap` function the behaviour of a single click can be customized. I hope it helps!

Comment: which version of bokeh are you using? (your code renders a blank canvas for me)

Comment: is it possible to capture right clicks by modifying your code ?

Comment: I haven't seen any way to capture right clicks in the event definitions of the current bokeh version: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/edd4fdd47674311baf88a6c32d63d0acb7560818/bokehjs/src/lib/core/ui_events.ts#L124. Bokeh relies on hammerjs which is oriented to work with mobile devices too, maybe that's why.